# More thorough grammar edit rejected to one that changed the case of one letter

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

I'm confused why [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18951397) on a post was rejected, when my edit included what another person changed and more, who also seemed to be the same person who reviewed and rejected my edit.

[Here is the edit that the reviewer applied instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49011916/2)

Whats up with this?

Comment: I don't think that was a correct review - ntg chose "reject and edit" per https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18951397, but you're right that their edit was much less thorough.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What are the other options he could chose from?

Comment: Accept, Improve Edit, Reject and Edit, Reject, Skip

Comment: Note that changing two words into a contraction is not fixing a mistake.  It is perfectly appropriate to not contract words.  In fact, it is considered informal to use a contraction, and more formal to avoid it, so it is possible that it was done intentionally (I doubt that was the case here though).  That someone felt inclined to leave the OP's voice intact rather than making an unnecessary change isn't wrong at all.  Of course there are a number of objective mistakes that you both missed...

Comment: @Servy I was mostly fixing the i to I with those changes, and I'm confused why he didn't fix them in his edit. I probably should have had my edit comment as "Fixed capitalization issues"

Comment: *I was mostly fixing the i to I with those changes* That might have been what the reviewer took issue with, actually. You made unnecessary changes to hit the 6 character minimum instead of fixing other issues with the post (the other lower case 'i', the misspelled word, etc.) On the other hand, I don't know why they'd Reject & Edit for that reason and not actually edit the post.

Comment: @BSMP: "reject and edit" robs the original editor of the 2 points that would have been earned for (in this reviewer's opinion) a sub-standard edit. One cannot edit a post while an edit is pending. ... That said, better try to stay away from attempting to fix questions that look bad and are likely to be closed and deleted. *My* opinion is that this is one of those.

Comment: @usr2564301 I feel like there should be a better option for situations like this. Like an "inefficient edit" option

Comment: @SPYBUG96 "Too minor" to exist but they got rid of it. That happened before I got access to the queue but if I recall other Meta conversations correctly, it was being abused and/or causing too many arguments.

Comment: @BSMP It wasn't being abused, it's just that a lot of people wanted to be minor edits that didn't substantively improve the post (because it's fast and easy, unlike making a useful edit), and lots of people wanted to approve those edits.  The main proponent of having a Too Minor reason and for rejection minor edits was Jeff, so when he left, the feature was removed.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Servy's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363969/more-thorough-grammar-edit-rejected-to-one-that-changed-the-case-of-one-letter#comment561311_363969), that changing contraction <strike>isn't</strike> is not necessarily an improvement, unless it's an actual grammatical correction for a specific sentence. And is potentially damaging or *conflicts with author's intent*.

That's possibly the reason it was rejected, and fixing a *suggested edit* is kinda counterproductive unless it's an easily fix and worthwhile.

The editor who rejected only changed one thing and missed various things - and no excuse as they'd seen them in your suggested edit. Arguably their edit was trivial and ironically would often be liable for being rejected. As a trusted reviewer, their "reject-edit" should have been a decent job, or instead they could have just rejected if they didn't want to edit.

Given the bad grammar present I presume the poster doesn't care about contraction, so I'd have likely "approve and edit" and ignored the contraction changes and fixed the things you missed.

**Things missed:**
*You:*

- Lowercase "i" at the end `How do i`

*User who rejected:*

- All lower case "i" and missing "?" at the end

*Both of you:*

- Grammaar/typo: `for invidual column`; E.g.`for an individual column`
- Grammar/tense: `My first try is to convert the object columns to
  float but I get the error message`; E.g. `My first attempt was to
  convert the object columns to float but I received this error message`

Pedantic? Not really, if you're going to edit, might as well do a good job and do the lot - it wasn't much text.

In all I think your edit was fine, and arguably should have been either "approve", or "approve and edit" to add the things you missed. I don't think it was worth rejecting, *certainly* not to make a much poorer edit.

But meh, it's not like the question is worth the edits, let alone us discussing it here :P

Comment: *or instead they could have just rejected if they didn't want to edit.* I guess they felt pretty strongly that the OP shouldn't get the rep and didn't want to risk other reviewers approving it.